# Extjs Load Mask

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, loadmask

I have a grid that when clicked takes a few seconds to pull up my pop-up window. I would like to have a 'loading...' message displayed while the pop-up window is loading. This is what I have so far:

```
    onCellClick : function(view, td, eOpts ) {
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
    myMask.show();
    Ext.create('myapp.view.DetailWindow', {
        title : 'my title',
        width : 900,
        approachRec : record
    });
    myMask.hide();

}
```

Right now this works perfectly, once I click on a cell in the grid my loading box appears then goes away once my 'DetailWindow' comes up.

However, once I close my window and click on another cell (or the same one) again. No loading box appears, but my 'detail' window does. What am I doing wrong?

What do I need to do in order to have my loading box pop up every time I click on  cell?

I'm using Extjs 4.2

Thanks,

Comment: What version of ExtJS?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Extjs 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've posted does not show() the window, it just creates it.  Below is some code that I've developed that "works" (I used a setTimeout to show the window after a 3 second delay, and then to hide the loading mask), but I think that to get to the heart of your problem, you are going to have to use your debugger, and see if it is displaying any errors in the console.

```
grid.on('cellclick', function() {
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
    myMask.show();
    var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Hello',
        height: 200,
        width: 400
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.show();
        myMask.hide();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Well the way I have my project set up my window works every time the cell is click (like it should.) My problem is, I can't get the loading window to show up every time the cell is clicked. Thanks though

Comment: Use your developer tools to debug, it may show some kind of error when you click on the cell and the loading mask doesn't show up